# Laraver rewrite language file from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Is it possible to write to a language file located at resources/lang/en/file.php from a controller? I moved my translations to database so user can edit them and now want to write the content from database to lang file each time content is changed.

Comment: What's the point of writing the translations to files if they're already in your database?

Comment: Seems to be easiest, because language files are default for laravel and that way i don't have to worry about performance or caching or handling fallback to default language or writing my own implementation for localization or anything else like that.

Comment: The alternative to using language files isn't rolling your own translation code. Have you searched for libraries that do this for you? I suspect that this has been solved before…

Comment: You should really look at this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager. Even if you don't use it as a whole, there are some parts (like publishing translations from db to files) you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write to anywhere in your filesystem provided you have the correct permissions. `file_put_contents` will write your contents to the desired path.

But you have the translation in a db, what's the use of writing to a file? You're just creating redundant data unnecessarily.

Edit:

You should define an entry in `config/filesystems.php` to use with the `Storage` facade.

```
    'translations' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => resource_path('translations'),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this function that helps me to write to resources folder:

```
app()['path.lang']
```

Comment: I ammended my answer for setting up and accessing filesystems.